# The ActiveRecord pattern and memory usage

Tags: php, activerecord

A lot of PHP's frameworks use the ActiveRecord pattern where the model class is responsible for the related db interaction e.g. finding/inserting/updating/deleting etc.

Isn't this essentially a terrible idea in terms of memory usage that is often relatively small on servers. The find methods could be static reducing memory usage for each object, but the remaining 3 **C**R**UD** methods won't be static. So, if you have 100 objects, isn't that 99 times more memory used for the CUD methods than, say, if you had a single repository for the model class? If so, why have the frameworks chosen the ActiveRecord pattern? Or, am I missing something here?

Comment: @icecub - don't worry - I have a troll following me around with a point to prove!

Comment: Why do you think a non-static method consumes more memory than a static one?

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks authors have to consider many aspects of development workflow and one of those is average resources available (CPU/memory consumption), but it is not the only one and these days it is not the most crucial one.

With resources in mind, you will need to make a cost/benefit analysis on how the RAM consumption increase is changing product costs and what benefits it brings. For example, frameworks targeting lightweight ARM devices or tiny servers will be really highly optimized from this perspective.

But **in general cases**, it's not worth it.

Why? Because on average the cost of RAM and CPU is relatively low, especially comparing to [software maintenance costs](http://blog.lookfar.com/blog/2016/10/21/software-maintenance-understanding-and-estimating-costs/). Many companies leverage cloud infrastructure providers (Google Cloud, AWS, etc.) these days saving quite a lot of money that, otherwise, they would need to spend on running their own servers.

Sometimes software maintenance costs can include *infrastructure costs*, so for simplicity sake, let's say it only includes
 - Developing new features
 - Making bug fixes
 - Performing code refactoring

So these alone cost a huge amount of money because each one of these points requires a developer's time. With such reasoning, we would rather optimize things that have an impact on those 3 actions, than things impacting resources usage.

And using ActiveRecord is one of such optimization. ActiveRecord is firstly relatively simple and simplicity is a crucial component of maintainability, and secondly really diverse (a lot of developers on the market are familiar with this pattern).

The pattern has [some disadvantages](https://medium.com/@vitaly.krenel/pragmatic-developer-learn-architecture-and-design-patterns-using-orm-and-activerecord-365dc3942fad#5355) but with a software architect or skilled-enough developer nearby, the team will be able to opt-out of ActiveRecord by replacing it with Data Access Object pattern (or Repository pattern).

So basically, frameworks choosing ActiveRecord (Laravel, Yii, etc.) are making a tradeoff, and usually, they consider different aspects than resource usage (memory/CPU), because it is insignificant in comparison to already mentioned software costs.